# How to create an array of array indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to create an array of of the number of elements I have in another array, but appending to the array in a loop gives me too many numbers.

```
 xaxis = np.zeros(len(newdates))
 for i in newdates:
    xaxis = np.append(xaxis, i)
```

Instead of [1,2,3,4,.....] like I want, it's giving me an array of [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,.....].

This seems like an easy question, but it's hanging me up for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the loop entirely with something like (assuming len(newdates) is 3):

```
>>> np.array(range(1, len(newdates)+1))
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: `np.arange` is probably faster

Comment: Ah, good call.  That would make the answer:
`np.arange(1, len(newdates)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are appending i values, the values inside newdates, to xaxis list, which is [0]*len(newdates). The code below illustrates this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> newdates = range(10)
>>> xaxis = np.zeros(len(newdates))
>>> for i in newdates:
...     xaxis = np.append(xaxis, i)
... 
>>> print xaxis
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.
  8.  9.]
```

I'm not sure about what you want to do, but I think it could be easily solved by:

```
xaxis = range(len(newdates))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
xaxis = np.append(xaxis, i)
```

try using the extend function

```
np.extend(i)
```

Comment: Doing that just keeps the array filled with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

While someone gave you a better way to do it I feel you should also see what you're doing wrong

```
for foo in bar:
```

loops over all of the elements of `bar` and calls them `foo` within the for loop. So if I had

```
newdates = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

and I did your code

```
xaxis = np.zeros(len(newdates))
 for i in newdates:
    xaxis = np.append(xaxis, i)
```

`xaxis` would be a bunch of 0's the length of `newdates` and then the numbers in `newdates` because within the loop `i` corresponds to an element of `newdates`